# how to use gem cancancan in layouts/application (in rails) ? it doesn't has controller to add authorize_resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how to use gem cancancan in layouts/application (rails) ?   it doesn't has controller to add authorize_resource ?
I want to use gems cancancan and rolify to manage layouts/application
navagation.

Comment: This question needs a little more substance before people can understand what you're asking for.

Comment: ok,thanks. I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

it needn't add authorize_resource to controller.
just add some code:(app/views/layouts/application.html.erb)

.......(yeild)

app/models/ability.rb

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
    if user.blank?
      cannot :manage, :all
    elsif user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
  end 
end

Then,  only the user which role is "admin" can see (yeild).